# JParameter showing error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I have used the below code for Joomla 1.5 & 2.5 but it is not supporting joomla 3

```
$pluginParams = new JParameter( $plugin->params );
```

Instead of i have used the below code in joomla 3

```
$params = new JInput();
$pluginParams = $params->get('params');
```

If i use the joomla 3, it conflicting with `article title`, `content-page navigation` and also with `K2` component.

Is there any solution to get the plugin params in joomla3.

Answer (score 0):

JParameter was deprecated for the whole lifetime of the 1.6-2.5 series and removed in Joomla 3. You should be using JForm in both.

Comment: we need to extend the class as "JForm" ?

Comment: Yes look at all the examples in the core (there are a lot).

Comment: Ok, i will check the examples in the core file